# Reading a .txt file and storing each line as a model

Tags: laravel

I have a `.txt` file that has names:

```
john doe
mary roe
...
...
```

I've a model `Person` which has the following `$fillable`:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'list_id',
        'name'
    ];
```

I'm trying to populate a specific `List` with the names from this specific file, but I'm sort of stuck trying to understand how to properly do this. I'm looking mostly to seed the database with a series of lists and names on each one (coming from a `.txt` file each list).

What would be the most convinient way to read the file and tell Laravel "Hey, store each line under (lets say) list 1!"?

Comment: please check answers below, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$file = new \SplFileObject(‘/path/to/your/file.txt’);

$list = List::where(…)->first(); // find the list matching your file 

while (!$file->eof()) {
    // assuming you have List::people() hasMany relation:
    $list->people()->create([
        ’name’ => trim($file->fgets()); // you can format, trim, sanitize your line here
    ]);
    // Without relation:
    Person::create([
        ’list_id’ => $list->id,
        ‘name’ => trim($file->fgets());
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution would be:

```
$file = new \SplFileObject("file.txt");
while (!$file->eof()) {
            // Echo one line from the file.
            $echo $file->fgets();
        }
$file = null;
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi SplFileObject is a neat way and object oriented, further info: [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)

```
$myFile = new SplFileObject("data.txt");

while (!$myFile->eof()) {
    echo $myFile->fgets() . PHP_EOL; //line N
//Here you can pass list id and the value retrieved above and store it on the DB
}
```